# Overriding EditorFor ID field within nested EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I am trying to explicitly change the ID and Name and Validate-For fields in my EditorFor outputs.

I have the following code:

```
Html.EditorFor(x => ViewBag.NestedFormDatas)
```

The above prefixes all of the fields with the name of the current Model.

My temporary solution is the following (I know it is far from ideal but it works!):

```
@Html.Raw(Html.EditorFor(x => ViewBag.NestedFormDatas).ToHtmlString().Replace("NestedForm", "DesiredPrefix"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you need to change the `id` and `name` attributes because you are not using view models. The following seems just so wrong:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => ViewBag.NestedFormDatas)
```

If you properly use view models, you don't need to changes names and ids, because the editor template will already generate proper values:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NestedFormDatas)
```

Anyway, one possibility is to write a custom editor template for the given type. So if we suppose that `NestedFormDatas` is a string type you could add the following `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml` editor template to override [the default one](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) and allow you to specify additional attributes:

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
    ViewData
)
```

and then:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NestedFormDatas, new { id = "foo" })
```

As far as the `name` attribute is concerned, this is not something that could be overriden with the `TextBox` helper. You will have to write your own helper if you ever needed to achieve that. But as I said if you use view models you never need to do that because that's exactly the purpose of view models: their are specifically defined to match the requirements of the given view.

So get rid of any traces of `ViewBag` in your code and start defining view models. You will see how much more fun and easy ASP.NET MVC will become.

Comment: Darin, is there a particular reason for prefixing id with @ in this case ? I know it's a must for "class" ... What is more, I don't think that your sample will work as EditorFor unlike TextBoxFor does not have an override that takes htmlAttributes as an input parameter

Comment: @torm, absolutely not. It was a bad copy-paste from my part. It's already removed.

Comment: oh, ok, I thought there is a some kind of trick behind this @ :) how about the EditorFor? Can you check ?

Comment: I will revisit the ViewModel approach but something like this to me seems like it shouldn't be too difficult. However, having said that I don't generally need to fight the framework and have found when I do it usually means I am doing it wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly may try to utilize htmlAttributes argument for overriding html properties with TextBoxFor :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>item.Name,new { id="newId"})
```

The concern I'm having looking at your code is that you're using dynamic view data dictionary (ViewBag) with a method that was meant for object properites of known type. I would strongly advise to replace ViewBag with a ViewModel having strongly typed collection. That would solve your problem with field naming ( I only assume, but that's the only thing I could think of as a reason for removing prefix from your input elements)

Comment: I would generally agree with using the ViewModel but the reason why I am not is because the Model is correct but the method I am using to create the view is slightly unorthodox. It is very hard to explain. 

Essentially within my view I have chosen to move a list of objects to another area which is within another editor template. This makes sense from a users perspective but within code I have to amend the ID fields to reconnect with the posted model.

Comment: My ID needs to become 'DesiredPrefix_0__NestedFormData_0__Property' previously it was 'NestedForm_0__NestedFormData_0__Property'

The DesiredPrefix in this case is another List on the Model.